# Python script to open many small images in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python

I have access to about 1000 satellite images that covers my country. Each of them is associated to a smaller image that is used for browsing the real deal. I would like to write a script that will sweep through the folders and opens all the "browsing" images. I can program in python but I am not sure on how to connect a script like this to QGIS. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Not quite what you intend, but building a virtual raster index on all those files with GDAL might speed up working with the whole dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one below, you will need to go into the crs settings and choose Use Project CRS otherwise it will pop up the CRS chooser for every image

```
##[Example scripts]=group
##Input_raster=raster
##Type=selection "GreyScale";"PseudoColor";"MultiColor"
##Red_band=number 1
##Green_band=number 2
##Blue_band=number 3
##Input_crs=crs

import os
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
import qgis.utils

from osgeo import gdal, ogr, osr
from processing.core.GeoAlgorithmExecutionException import \
        GeoAlgorithmExecutionException
from processing.tools.raster import *

raster = gdal.Open(Input_raster)

rasterPath = os.path.dirname(Input_raster)
rasterBaseName,rasterExt = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(Input_raster))

#project coordinate system
#canvas = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas()
#canvas.mapRenderer().setProjectionsEnabled(True)
#canvas.mapRenderer().setDestinationCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(Input_crs))

fileList = os.listdir(rasterPath)

for file in fileList:
    if os.path.splitext(file)[1] == rasterExt:
       fileName = rasterPath + '/' + file
       rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(fileName,file)
       if not rlayer.isValid():
          raise GeoAlgorithmExecutionException( 'error loading :- ' + file)
       QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(rlayer)
       rlayer.setCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(Input_crs))
       bandCnt = rlayer.bandCount()
       if bandCnt > 1:
          if Red_band > bandCnt or Green_band > bandCnt or Blue_band > bandCnt:
             raise GeoAlgorithmExecutionException( 'Only ' + bandCnt + 'layers in file')
          if Type == 0:
             rlayer.setDrawingStyle('MultiBandSingleBandGray')
             rlayer.renderer().setGrayBand(Red_band)
          elif Type == 1:
             rlayer.setDrawingStyle('MultiBandSingleBandPseudoColor')
             rlayer.renderer().setGrayBand(Red_band)
          else:
             rlayer.setDrawingStyle('MultiBandColor')
             rlayer.renderer().setRedBand(Red_band)
             rlayer.renderer().setGreenBand(Green_band)
             rlayer.renderer().setBlueBand(Blue_band)
       else:
           if Type == 0:
              if rlayer.rasterType() == 1:
                 rlayer.setDrawingStyle('PalettedSingleBandGray')
              else:
                 rlayer.setDrawingStyle('SingleBandGray')
           elif Type == 1:
              if rlayer.rasterType() == 1:
                 rlayer.setDrawingStyle('PalettedSingleBandPseudoColor')
              else:
                 rlayer.setDrawingStyle('SingleBandPseudoColor')
           else:
              if rlayer.rasterType() == 1:
                 rlayer.setDrawingStyle('PalettedColor')
              else:
                 rlayer.setDrawingStyle('SingleBandGray')
           rlayer.renderer().setGrayBand(Red_band)
#zoom to extent of data
qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().zoomToFullExtent()
```

Comment: Although the question is already 8 months old thanks for the code. It will be useful for future visitors!

Comment: I'll definetely try this, looks very promising thank you. I'll accept it for now.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that you would want to use the [os.walk](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) function found in the os module that comes with Python to go through all the directories.  You could then use the QgsRasterLayer function to load the image into your script.  Here's an example for QgsRasterLayer from the [PyQGIS Documentation](http://www.qgis.org/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html#raster-layers):

```
fileName = "/path/to/raster/file.tif"
fileInfo = QFileInfo(fileName)
baseName = fileInfo.baseName()
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(fileName, baseName)
if not rlayer.isValid():
  print "Layer failed to load!"
```

Hope that this helps!

Comment: Your answer is a link only answer with no helpful context, please update.

Answer (score 1):

Heres another script to loop through all the raster layers and change the contrast stretch

```
##[Example scripts]=group
##Limits=selection "MinMax";"StdDev";"Cumulative"
##Stretch=selection "NoStretch";"StretchToMinMax";"StretchAndClipToMinMax";"ClipToMinMax"

import os
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
import qgis.utils

layers = qgis.utils.iface.legendInterface().layers()

for layer in layers:
    layerType = layer.type()
    if layerType == QgsMapLayer.RasterLayer:
       if Stretch==0:
          ContrastEnhancement = QgsContrastEnhancement.NoEnhancement
       elif Stretch==1:
            ContrastEnhancement = QgsContrastEnhancement.StretchToMinimumMaximum
       elif Stretch==2:
            ContrastEnhancement = QgsContrastEnhancement.StretchAndClipToMinimumMaximum
       elif Stretch==3:
            ContrastEnhancement = QgsContrastEnhancement.ClipToMinimumMaximum

       if Limits==0:
          layer.setContrastEnhancement(ContrastEnhancement,QgsRaster.ContrastEnhancementMinMax)
       elif Limits==1:
          layer.setContrastEnhancement(ContrastEnhancement,QgsRaster.ContrastEnhancementStdDev)
       elif Limits==2:
           layer.setContrastEnhancement(ContrastEnhancement,QgsRaster.ContrastEnhancementCumulativeCut)
       layer.triggerRepaint()
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is exactly what [Load Them All](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/loadthemall/) plugin does. It can load several vector or raster files at once from a base directory you set.

Additionally, the plugin can:

- Load rasters of a particular format (e.g., only .tif)
- Create groups in the ToC to reflect your folders in the hard disk. Groups can be nested.
- Turn off loaded layers.
- Load layers based on an alphanumeric filter against layer names.
- Load layers based on a bounding box filter against layer extents.
- Load layers based on vector/raster type filter.

The loading process performs well, as the plugin takes care of switching the canvas render flag and the CRS definition for new layers window off while loading layers. Both canvas render flag and CRS for new layers are switched back to their original states after loading all layers.

[image]